# What is the regular expression for matching a string that starts with "<tag1 attribute="0">" and ends with "</tag>"?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

What is the regular expression for matching a string that starts with `<tag1 attribute="0">` and ends with `</tag>`?

Comment: Are you trying to parse XML with RegEx? That's not a good idea since nested tags will not be properly understood.

Comment: Don't parse XML with regular expressions. It's been said here a million times - use an XML parser for XML.

Comment: The answer to your question is something like `/^<tag1 attribute="0">.*<\/tag>$/` (depending on the regex variant), and when you understand what this does, you will hopefully realise that the question you asked is not the question you meant to ask.

Comment: @hvd What I am trying to do is select individually elements of a not well formed xml doc. Meaning its large and it had MANY root nodes

Comment: This is returning false.....
Regex r = new Regex(@"/^<tag attribute=""0"">.*<\/tag>$/"); Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(@"<tag attribute=""0"">dergergerg<\tag>"))

Comment: because you put a backslash instead of a slash on the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `<tag1 attribute=”0“>.*?<\/tag>`

[Test code](http://ideone.com/XlH17):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string input = @"this is <tag1 attribute=""0""> and ends with </tag>, okay?";
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"<tag1 attribute=""0"">.*?<\/tag>",
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Match!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is returning false Omega... 

Regex r = new Regex(@"/^<tag attribute=""0"">.*<\/tag>$/");
            Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(@"<tag attribute=""0"">dergergerg<\tag>"));